"Failed to load _MLModelProxy: No module named 'coremltools.libcoremlpython'"when converting an ONNX model to CoreML with onnx-coreml lib. How to fix?
I try to use the onnx-coreml lib to convert an ONNX model to CoreML:
import onnx
from onnx_coreml import convert
onnx_model = onnx.load('model.onnx')
coreml_model = convert(onnx_model)
coreml_model.save('model.mlmodel')

Error:
C:\code\export_model_to_coreml.py 
scikit-learn version 1.3.2 is not supported. Minimum required version: 0.17. Maximum required version: 1.1.2. Disabling scikit-learn conversion API.
Failed to load _MLModelProxy: No module named 'coremltools.libcoremlpython'
Fail to import BlobReader from libmilstoragepython. No module named 'coremltools.libmilstoragepython'
Fail to import BlobWriter from libmilstoragepython. No module named 'coremltools.libmilstoragepython'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\code\export_model_to_coreml.py", line 2, in <module>
    from onnx_coreml import convert
  File "C:\Users\dernoncourt\anaconda3\envs\py311\Lib\site-packages\onnx_coreml\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .converter import convert
  File "C:\Users\dernoncourt\anaconda3\envs\py311\Lib\site-packages\onnx_coreml\converter.py", line 35, in <module>
    from coremltools.converters.nnssa.coreml.graph_pass.mlmodel_passes import remove_disconnected_layers, transform_conv_crop
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'coremltools.converters.nnssa'

Process finished with exit code 1

How to fix?
